# why isnt my function outputting to my table?

Tags: javascript, html

im wondering why my function isn't outputting to my table when i change the variable "n" through its text box.

I've never tried this before... And I'm thinking the cause might be because i'm trying to use a loop within a function and may also have syntax erros.

```html
  <label>N:</label>
<br>
<input id="N" type="number" onchange="fraccsum()" value=1>
<br>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>N </td>
        <td>fractions in decimal form</td>
    </tr>
<script>


// function pulls N value and displays on the table
function fraccsum() {
    // Pulls N Value
    var N = document.getElementById("N").value;
    var Sum=0;
    // my formula to find the sum of the fraction 
    for (var fraction = 1; fraction <= N; fraction++) {
    ThisN = 1/fraction;
    Sum = Sum + ThisN;
//this writes down all the answers
    document.write("<tr><td>"+ fraction +"</td>");

    document.write("<td>" + "" + ThisN +"</td></tr>");
}
document.write("<tr><td>" + "Total:" + Sum +"</td></tr>");
</script>
```

Comment: variables are case sensitive. sum vs. Sum (for starters).

Comment: Don’t use document.write after the document has finished loading, or it will create a new page document replacing the whole screen

Comment: thank you guys for pointing these out to me

Comment: The `for` loop is not closed. Missing a `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I get a error on the variable "sum", you have it in both uppercase and lowercase (Sum & sum). So choose one and stick to it.

Second you didn't close off the function fraccsum.

Third you shouldn't use document.write since its bad practice.
I got the code rendered hope this helps.

```html
    <label>N:</label>
    <br>
    <input id="N" type="number" onchange="fraccsum()" value=1>
    <br>
  
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>N </td>
            <td>fractions in decimal form</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <!-- Add a placeholder for the tavle -->
    <table id="placeholderTable"></table>
    <script>
    
    
    // function pulls N value and displays on the table
    function fraccsum() {
        // Pulls N Value
        var N = document.getElementById("N").value;
        var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholderTable");
        var sum=0;
        var renderHtml = "";
        // my formula to find the sum of the fraction 
        for (var fraction = 1; fraction <= N; fraction++) {
        ThisN = 1/fraction;
        sum = sum + ThisN;
        
    //this writes down all the answers
            renderHtml += "<tr><td>"+ fraction +"</td>" + "<td>" + "" + ThisN +"</td></tr>";

        // document.write("<tr><td>"+ fraction +"</td>");
        //     console.log(fraction);
        // document.write("<td>" + "" + ThisN +"</td></tr>");
    }
    renderHtml += "<tr><td>" + "Total:" + sum +"</td></tr>";
    placeholder.innerHTML = renderHtml;
    // document.write("<tr><td>" + "Total:" + sum +"</td></tr>");
    }
    </script>
```

Also even though I didn't include it in your code i would suggest you have a look at template literals, makes for cleaner code in my opinion.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals